# simple else with while in loop not working

Tags: php

My code is working as for my needs. But the only thing bugging me is
 the "else" is not working. When i search for a correct record the
 record will appear and it was running fine. But if i Incorrectly
 search a record nothing will happen. i am expecting "Records not Found" will echo but nothing happen.

---

```
}else{
       echo "Records not found";
    }
```

---

This is the whole code.

```
      <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my1stdb") or die("could not connect");

$set = $_POST['search'];


if ($set) {
    $show   = "SELECT * FROM users where email='$set'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $show);
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "Registrant Found";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $rows['username'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $rows['fullname'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $rows['password'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $rows['email'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }

} else {
    echo "Records not found";
}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mysqli_num_rows()` along with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`:-

```
<?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my1stdb") or die("could not connect");

    $set = $_POST['search']; 


    if($set) {
        $show="SELECT * FROM users where email='$set'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$show) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ // check data present or not
            while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ // for lighter array due to associative indexes only
                echo "Registrant Found";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $rows['username'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $rows['fullname'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $rows['password'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $rows['email'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<br/>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Records not found";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Please insert search term";
    }

?>
</table>
```

***Note:-*** Your code is wide-open for SQL INJECTION. to prevent from it use `prepared statements`

***Reference:-***

[mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: OMG THAT WAS AWESOME! It works! Thank you ! your code was the best. Cheers!

Comment: What if there is an error in the query? No row number will be returned.

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: @kelvingallos  please check my edited answer. I have  added some note and instruction  which is most important for you. Please check and try to convert code in that way. It will prevent your code from SQL INJECTION.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of results returned.

```
if($set) {
    $show="SELECT * FROM users where email='$set'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$show);

    $recordCount = 0;

    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $recordCount++;
            echo "Registrant Found";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $rows['username'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $rows['fullname'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $rows['password'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $rows['email'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<br/>";
    }
    if($recordCount==0){
        echo "Records not found";
    }

}
```